# How to view ActualNumberOfRows in SQL Server execution plan

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've been trying to diagnose a performance issue in my database and have googled a lot on maxdop. I have seen in many places where ActualNumberOfRows, ActualRebinds etc. are shown in properties view but the first thing I see is DefinedValues.

After running execution plan I right click an Index Scan for example and expect to see these fields so I can determine how rows are distributed amongst threads.

I am using SQL Server 2005 Enterprise.

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious are you definitely looking at the Actual Execution Plan (not the generic cached plan).

Comment: yikes, thats what it was... got in a bad habit of clicking estimated execution plan.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

include the Actual Execution plan and in that click on the arrow button, there we can see the Actual Number of Rows